# TensorFlow returns the same value when using numpy random function

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, random

I am using Tensorflow with numpy random function, but the output is the same value. How can I generate different values? You may recommend use native tf random functions, but I need to use numpy random function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random


def get_rand():
    return random.randint(0,5)

a = get_rand()
tfprint = tf.Print(a, [a])

for i in range(10):
    print(print(get_rand()))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(10):
        sess.run(tfprint)
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it printed 10 different random numbers. What is the issue?

Comment: Numpy part does generate random numbers, but the Tensorflow part will not.

Answer (score 1):

With tf.py_func, turn the Numpy function to Tensorflow function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random


def get_rand():
    return random.randint(0,5)

a = tf.py_func(get_rand, [], tf.int64)
tfprint = tf.Print(a, [a])

for i in range(10):
    print(get_rand())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(10):
        sess.run(tfprint)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed data using `placeholders` and the `feed_dict` variable:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import random


def get_rand():
    return random.randint(0,5)

a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
tfprint = tf.Print(a, [a])


with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(10):
        sess.run(tfprint, feed_dict={a: get_rand()})
```

You may read more about placeholders [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but in my problem, I can't use the feed_dict.

Comment: What is preventing you from using them?

Comment: My original problem is more complex than giving example. It is about data augmentation.